# How do I make a desktop shortcut which links to a specific element of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a shortcut to a search bar on a website. After this shortcut has been created I am going to give it a keyboard shortcut.

How do I focus on a specific element on a page when it is opened for the first time in a browser?

I have researched bookmarklets, but I don't think they do what I want them to do.
I also had a look at javascript, and I have a feeling I will need to use:

```
document.findElementByName("").focus()
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

EDIT: It's worth noting it is not my webpage. It is a public webpage.

Comment: Google for "html autofocus".

Comment: had a look. It's worth noting it isn't my webpage, its a public webpage and I don't have access to the html

Comment: That's quite relevant information you should put in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the element has an id, say `importantElement`, then it should be sufficient to add `#importantElement` to the URL string.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have an id, just a name